# Java: How to load data from serialized file into JTextFields?

Tags: java, user-interface, serialization

I already made a serialized file using a textfile which contain data of Employees for example their names and employee number etc.

Now I want to populate my JTextFields with data from the serialized file I made. How do I take this step?

Here is my code:

```
 import java.io.*;



 public class CreateCustomerSer
 {

 public static void main(String args[])  {
 Customer cust;

 try
    {

       ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream("customer.ser"));


       output.writeObject(new Customer(100, "Estelle", "Zietsman", "Bellville", false));
       output.writeObject(new Customer(200, "Karin", "Swart", "Welgemoed", true));
       output.writeObject(new Customer(300, "Kruben", "Naidoo", "Sea Point", true));
       output.writeObject(new Customer(400, "Wilhelm", "Rothman", "Manenberg", true));
       output.writeObject(new Customer(500, "Gillian", "Khan", "Bellville", true));
       output.writeObject(new Customer(600, "Denise", "Lakay", "Bishops court", false));
       output.close();

       ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("customer.ser"));
       while (true) {
         cust = (Customer) input.readObject();
         System.out.println(cust.toString());
        }
   }
    catch(EOFException fnfe )
    {
        return;        
    }
    catch(IOException fnfe )
    {
        System.out.println(fnfe);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException fnfe )
    {
        System.out.println(fnfe);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    }
   }
```

Comment: You conventionally usually take this step by reading information from file, parsing it and then putting parsed data on UI.

Comment: And until we have more info about your actual problem, the above is the only answer you'll get.

Comment: I understand, so I added my code for more details.